# ffmpeg showing "Error initializing output stream 0:0"

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am running the following command

```
ffmpeg -i DJI_0001.MOV DJI_0001.mp4
```

in order to convert the video to mp4 from MOV with no other property changes.

The issue is that I am getting:

```
ffmpeg version N-86863-g2ba20d799a-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.4.0 (Debian 6.4.0-2) 20170724
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
  libavcodec     57.102.100 / 57.102.100
  libavformat    57. 76.100 / 57. 76.100
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 95.100 /  6. 95.100
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'DJI_0001.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 538182144
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2017-07-23T17:04:58.000000Z
    location        : 
    location-{    : 
    comment         : 0.9.142
  Duration: 00:00:17.89, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 60017 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 4096x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 256:135], 60014 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-07-23T17:04:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : DJI.AVC
      encoder         : Dji AVC encoder
File 'DJI_0001.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x3ed56a0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x3ed56a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

I see no other error message that would indicate an underlying problem. Could anybody please give me some info on how should I fix it?

Comment: Odd that it does not show an additional error message. Does it fail with a synthetic input? `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc2=s=4096x2160:d=17.89:r=24000/1001 output.mp4` If no, then provide the input file if possible. If yes, then I'm not sure what the issue is because it works for me (but with a different version).

Comment: If you just want to change the container, you can run `ffmpeg -i DJI_0001.MOV -c copy DJI_0001.mp4`. You can also run your command with -report added and share the log.

Comment: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc2=s=4096x2160:d=17.89:r=24000/1001 output.mp4` produces the same error. But `ffmpeg -i DJI_0001.MOV -c copy DJI_0001.mp4` works well and does what I want (which is conversion to mp4)

Comment: I compiled version 2ba20d799a and tried again and it still works for me, but I'm not sure what x264 version was being used in yours. Not sure what the cause is, but I guess it doesn't really matter since you just wanted to re-mux and that seemed to work for you. I'm curious if `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc2=s=4096x2160:d=17.89:r=24000/1001 -c:v mpeg4 output.mp4` also fails.

Comment: That last command does work and it does produce a sample video with a bunch of color bars.